# How to continue running my service even when the user clears the app from the "android history stack"?

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

By "android history stack", I mean this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/70CsStGTxls/maxresdefault.jpg . I am sorry, but I don't know what that is called technically. I want a Service to keep running in background indefinitely. I have created a IntentService(also called a StartedService) and used it as follows:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(
       new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              doSomeTask();
              handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
           }
       }
   );
```

The task continues to run even if the app has been closed by the user. But if the user removes the app from the screen shown in the link(which is generally obtained by clicking the lower right button in most android devices), by swiping left or right, then my service stops running. I want it to continue running. I know that is possible because this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.reborn.pro&hl=en manages to continue running even if it is removed from the "android history stack". Could someone tell me how to do it??

Answer (score 0):

If you want your service to run "indefinitely" in the background you should use a service, not an IntentService.

In the Service's onStartCommand you return START_STICKY, which will tell Android that you want your sevice to keep on running.
Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

The service can still be killed, but it will then be restarted by Android at a later time.

Edit: You should make sure that your application can be killed / started at different times as Android might need those resources elsewhere for a short duration or to save battery.